# SET HEADER frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'GOFORIT' on Canvas FB apps

Tags: php, facebook

I have fb Apps https://apps.facebook.com/e_voting_competition/, then I have problem when I want to authenticate using server side.

the problem is **Refused to display a frame because it set **'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.** , I have solution at this link [Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)

but it's still not showing my authentication login . and for make sure set the header is work I give you the screenshot

[image]

do you have any suggestion for solve this problem ?

Comment: You can not call the Login dialog within any kind of frame, you have to call it within the top window instance. So either redirect the user there via JavaScript (`top.location.href=…`), or use `target=_top` on the link you use to trigger login.

Comment: if like that redirect page after success will be out of iframe or canvas fb apps. it's make me sad

Comment: Well then set the `redirect_uri` parameter so that it points back to your canvas address. Or just use the JS SDK and it's FB.login method, that makes for a nicer user experience as well (IMHO).

Comment: nice,  I am done with your suggestion by redirect after success login using sosmed

and for security and separate between login by fb from default site , create function for detection http referrer is match with facebook auth.